# running simple bash script fails with Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: 14.04, bash

I am trying to install Anaconda3 in ubuntu14.04 like this:

```
seyyedhossein@hossein:~$ sh Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

and I get :

```
Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh: 16: Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh: 0: not found
Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh: 61: Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh: 0: not found
Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh: 75: Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

what is the problem here?
I had installed it on another account (which was initially downloaded from) successfully. but when I logged in to my new account, it just wont run!

**Update:**
The output of the cat command :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Continuum Analytics, Inc.
# All rights reserved.
#
# Name: Anaconda3
# Version: 4.2.0
# Packages: 195
# PLAT:  linux-64
# DESCR: 4.1.1-889-g7ce9b7f
# BYTES: 478051940
# LINES: 558
# MD5:   1ee1f5cb1d92a230e59cc5fce0dca5ba

unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
echo "$0" | grep '\.sh$' >/dev/null
if (( $? )); then
    echo 'Please run using "bash" or "sh", but not "." or "source"' >&2
    return 1
fi

THIS_DIR=$(cd $(dirname $0); pwd)
THIS_FILE=$(basename $0)
THIS_PATH="$THIS_DIR/$THIS_FILE"
PREFIX=$HOME/anaconda3
BATCH=0
FORCE=0

while getopts "bfhp:" x; do
    case "$x" in
        h)
            echo "usage: $0 [options]

Installs Anaconda3 4.2.0

    -b           run install in batch mode (without manual intervention),
                 it is expected the license terms are agreed upon
    -f           no error if install prefix already exists (force)
    -h           print this help message and exit
    -p PREFIX    install prefix, defaults to $PREFIX
"
            exit 2
            ;;
        b)
            BATCH=1
            ;;
        f)
            FORCE=1
            ;;
        p)
            PREFIX="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        ?)
            echo "Error: did not recognize option, please try -h"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done

# verify the size of the installer
wc -c "$THIS_PATH" | grep 478051940 >/dev/null
if (( $? )); then
    echo "ERROR: size of $THIS_FILE should be 478051940 bytes" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if [[ $BATCH == 0 ]] # interactive mode
then
    if [[ `uname -m` != 'x86_64' ]]; then
        echo -n "WARNING:
    Your operating system appears not to be 64-bit, but you are trying to
    install a 64-bit version of Anaconda3.
    Are sure you want to continue the installation? [yes|no]
[no] >>> "
        read ans
        if [[ ($ans != "yes") && ($ans != "Yes") && ($ans != "YES") &&
              ($ans != "y") && ($ans != "Y") ]]
```

Comment: On Ubuntu, `sh` is not `bash` - see [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the script: though it claims in its own documentation that it can be run by `sh`, i.e. by any standard POSIX shell, it actually requires `bash`.

The construct `(( $? ))` is not valid POSIX sh, nor is `($ans != "yes")` when `$ans` is empty.  They are hardly valid in `bash` either (TBH, this is the first time in 20yrs I see the idiom `(( $? ))`) but apparently `bash` lets it pass.

Solution: run using bash: `bash Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`

Answer (score 1):

The sh command that you're giving assumes that the .sh file is in your home directory. It may be located elsewhere, in which case you have to give it a pathname to where the file is located.

Example: if the file Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh is located on your Desktop, you can:

```
cd ~/Desktop
bash Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

or

```
bash ~/Desktop/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, please edit your question to include the output of:

```
cat Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh | head -n 76
```

Comment: Thanks but  the Anaconda3 script is located in the home directory! yet it does not find it!

Comment: There are alot of weird symbols  being displayed on the terminal after I entered that cat command!

Comment: Ah, because there's binary code inside the .sh file! Try this: `cat Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh | head -n 76` and `ls -al Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Thanks alot for your time dear heynnema, but I used bash instead of sh and it ran just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I used bash instead of sh, and the script ran just fine!
it seems sh was not meant to be used with this one!